# Generating Dinosaur names with Tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I try to adapt ["Text generation with an RNN"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation#build_the_model) tutorial to generate new dinosaur names from a list of the existing ones. For training RNN tutorial text is divided into example character sequences of equal length:

```
# Read, then decode for py2 compat.
text = open(path_to_file, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
# The unique characters in the file
vocab = sorted(set(text))
idx2char = np.array(vocab)
# Creating a mapping from unique characters to indices
char2idx = {u:i for i, u in enumerate(vocab)}
# The maximum length sentence we want for a single input in characters
seq_length = 100
examples_per_epoch = len(text)//(seq_length+1)
# Create training examples / targets
char_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(text_as_int)
# Convert to sequences of the same length
sequences = char_dataset.batch(seq_length+1, drop_remainder=True)
# Sequences as text
for item in sequences.take(2):
    print("----")
    print(repr(''.join(idx2char[item.numpy()])))
```

Output:

```
----
'First Citizen:\nBefore we proceed any further, hear me speak.\n\nAll:\nSpeak, speak.\n\nFirst Citizen:\nYou '
----
'are all resolved rather to die than to famish?\n\nAll:\nResolved. resolved.\n\nFirst Citizen:\nFirst, you k'
```

My problem differs from tutorial in that I have a list of names of different length instead of monolith of text:

```
aachenosaurus
aardonyx
abdallahsaurus
abelisaurus
abrictosaurus
abrosaurus
abydosaurus
acanthopholis
```

In my case character sequences are names. As long as I can't train RNN on sequences with different length (please, correct me if I am wrong here) I need to pad all my names with spaces to a size of a longest name, which is 26.

My longest name is `lisboasaurusliubangosaurus`, so, for example, `aardonyx` shoud be padded as:

```
"lisboasaurusliubangosaurus"
"aardonyx                  "
```

I tried to pad my sequences with:

```
# Convert individual characters to sequences of the desired size.
sequences = char_dataset.padded_batch(seq_length+1, padded_shapes=seq_length, drop_remainder=True)
```

Which results in error:

```
ValueError: The padded shape (26,) is not compatible with the corresponding input component shape ().
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to train Tensorflow RNN with sequences of variable length?
- How to pad short sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: can you link the data?

Comment: Dino RNN from scratch with data: https://github.com/prateekkarkare/rnn_char_modelling and TF tutorial with data: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation#build_the_model